# После выполнения функции, дальнейший код не выполняется(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет.

Я только недавно стал изучать программирование, на просторах интернета наткнулся на код простого классификатора вопросов и решил переработать его под определитель времён в английском языке, но столкнулся с проблемой после запуска этих функций мой код не выполняется

Прикрепляю эти функции:

```py
def set_tense():
    def text_cleaner(text):
        text = text.lower()  # refurbishment to lowercase 
        stemmer = Stemmer('russian')
        text = ' '.join(stemmer.stemWords(text.split()))
        text = re.sub(r'\b\d+\b', ' digit ', text)  # change of digits
        return text

        # downloading data from a file

    def load_data():
        data = {'text': [], 'tag': []}
        for line in open('times.txt'):
            if not ('#' in line):
                row = line.split("@")
                data['text'] += [row[0]]
                data['tag'] += [row[(len(row)) - 1]]
        return data

    # lerning

    def train_test_split(data, validation_split=0.1):
        sz = len(data['text'])
        indices = np.arange(sz)
        np.random.shuffle(indices)

        X = [data['text'][i] for i in indices]
        Y = [data['tag'][i] for i in indices]
        nb_validation_samples = int(validation_split * sz)

        return {
            'train': {'x': X[:-nb_validation_samples], 'y': Y[:-nb_validation_samples]},
            'test': {'x': X[-nb_validation_samples:], 'y': Y[-nb_validation_samples:]}
        }

    # - - - -

    def openai():
        data = load_data()
        D = train_test_split(data)
        text_clf = Pipeline([
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
            ('clf', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge')),
        ])
        text_clf.fit(D['train']['x'], D['train']['y'])
        predicted = text_clf.predict(D['train']['x'])

        # Starting test a program

        zz = []
        zz.append(direct_speech)
        predicted = text_clf.predict(zz)
        predicted[0] = predicted[0][1:-1]
        predicted[0] = str(predicted[0])
        print(predicted[0])
        return predicted[0]

    # - - - -
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(openai())
```

Comment: А как вы делаете вызов функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить отдельную функцию внутри другой функции. Так не получится. Почитайте про области видимости.

Локальная переменная определяется внутри функции и доступна только из этой функции, то есть имеет локальную область видимости. Это касается и функций в теле вашей функции set_tense.

Вам нужно выполнять эту функцию внутри set_tense или пересмотреть структуру. Либо создавать эти функции в глобальной области видимости, либо переделать set_tense в класс.